# my deep deterministic policy gradient model is not learning anything even after 2000 iteration

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

i have tried different hyper parameters and number of layers and node but my model is not learning anything even after 2000 iteration and i have also tried MountainCarContinuous-v0 environment but that also didn't work.

i have tried different architecture and model from github but still my model is not learning anything

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import random
import gym
import pylab
import sys

from keras.initializers import RandomUniform
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, Add, Concatenate, Flatten, GaussianNoise, Lambda
from keras import backend as K
from collections import deque

config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
K.set_session(sess)

EPISODES = 100000

class Actor(object):

    def __init__(self, sess, state_size, action_size, TAU, lr, action_bound=1, load=False):
        self.sess = sess
        self.TAU = TAU
        self.lr = lr
        self.load = load
        self.action_bound = action_bound

        self.model, self.weights, self.state = self.bulid_network(state_size, action_size)
        self.target_model, self.target_weights, self.target_weights = self.bulid_network(state_size, action_size)
        self.q_grads = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, action_size])
        self.grads = tf.gradients(self.model.output, self.weights, -self.q_grads)
        self.optimize = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr).apply_gradients(zip(self.grads, self.weights))
        self.sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        if self.load:
            self.model.load_weights("./DDPG_Actor.h5")
            self.target_model.load_weights("./DDPG_Actor_target.h5")

    def train(self, state, grads):
        self.sess.run(self.optimize, feed_dict={self.state : state, self.q_grads : grads})

    def update(self):
        W, target_W = self.model.get_weights(), self.target_model.get_weights()
        for i in range(len(W)):
            target_W[i] = self.TAU*W[i] + (1 - self.TAU)*target_W[i]
        self.target_model.set_weights(target_W)

    def save(self):
        self.model.save_weights("./DDPG_Actor.h5")
        self.target_model.save_weights("./DDPG_Actor_target.h5")

    def bulid_network(self, state_size, action_size):
        input = Input(shape=[state_size])
        X = Dense(400, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(input)
        X = Dense(300, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(X)
        output = Dense(action_size, activation='tanh', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(X)
        output = Lambda(lambda i : i*self.action_bound)(output)
        model = Model(input=input, output=output)
        return model, model.trainable_weights, input 


class Critic(object):

    def __init__(self, sess, state_size, action_size, TAU, lr, load=False):
        self.sess = sess
        self.TAU = TAU
        self.lr = lr
        self.load = load
        self.optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr)

        self.model, self.state, self.action = self.build_network(state_size, action_size)
        self.target_model, self.target_state, self.target_action = self.build_network(state_size, action_size)
        self.q_grads = tf.gradients(self.model.output, self.action)
        self.sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        if self.load:
            self.model.load_weights("./DDPG_Critic.h5")
            self.target_model.load_weights("./DDPG_Critic_target.h5")

    def gradients(self, state, action):
        return self.sess.run(self.q_grads, feed_dict={self.state : state, self.action : action})[0]

    def save(self):
        self.model.save_weights("./DDPG_Critic.h5")
        self.target_model.save_weights("./DDPG_Critic_target.h5")

    def update(self):
        W, target_W = self.model.get_weights(), self.target_model.get_weights()
        for i in range(len(W)):
            target_W[i] = self.TAU*W[i] + (1 - self.TAU)*target_W[i]
        self.target_model.set_weights(target_W)        

    def build_network(self, state_size, action_size):
        S = Input(shape=[state_size])
        A = Input(shape=[action_size])
        X1 = Dense(400, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(S)
        X2 = Dense(400, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(A)
        X = Add()([X1,X2])
        X = Dense(300, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(X)
        output = Dense(action_size, activation='linear', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(X)
        model = Model(inputs=[S, A], outputs=output)
        model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(lr=self.lr))
        return model, S, A


class DDPG(object):
    def __init__(self, sess, state_size, action_size, action_bound=1, memory_size=5000, batch_size=64, actor_lr=0.0001, critic_lr=0.001, gamma=0.99, TAU=0.001):
        self.sess = sess
        self.state_size = state_size
        self.action_size = action_size
        self.memory = deque(maxlen=memory_size)
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.actor_lr = actor_lr
        self.critic_lr = critic_lr
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.TAU = TAU
        self.train_start = 1000
        self.epsilon =  1
        self.epsilon_min = 0.001
        self.mu = 0.0
        self.x = 0
        self.theta = 0.01
        self.sigma = 0.1
        self.epsilon_decay = (self.epsilon - self.epsilon_min) / 100000


        self.actor = Actor(sess, state_size, action_size, TAU, actor_lr,action_bound, load=False)
        self.critic = Critic(sess, state_size, action_size, TAU, critic_lr, load=False)

    def append(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):
        self.memory.append((state, action, reward, next_state, done))
        if self.epsilon > self.epsilon_min :
          self.epsilon -= self.epsilon_decay

    def OU(self):
        dx = self.theta*(self.mu - self.x) + self.sigma*np.random.randn(1)
        self.x += dx
        return self.x

    def get_action(self, state):
        action =  self.actor.model.predict(state)[0]
        return action + self.OU()*self.epsilon

    def save(self):
        self.actor.save()
        self.critic.save()

    def train(self):
        if len(self.memory) < self.train_start:
            return

        batch_size = min(self.batch_size, len(self.memory))
        mini_batch = random.sample(self.memory, batch_size)

        states = np.asarray([e[0] for e in mini_batch])
        states = np.reshape(states, [batch_size, self.state_size])
        actions = np.asarray([e[1] for e in mini_batch])
        rewards = np.asarray([e[2] for e in mini_batch])
        next_states = np.asarray([e[3] for e in mini_batch])
        next_states = np.reshape(next_states, [batch_size, self.state_size])
        done = np.asarray([e[4] for e in mini_batch])
        target = np.zeros_like(actions)

        target_q_values = self.critic.target_model.predict([next_states, self.actor.target_model.predict(next_states)])
        for i in range(len(mini_batch)):
            if done[i]:
                target[i] = rewards[i]

            else :
                target[i] = rewards[i] + self.gamma*target_q_values[i]

        loss = self.critic.model.train_on_batch([states, actions], target)
        action_for_grad = self.actor.model.predict(states)
        q_grads = self.critic.gradients(states,action_for_grad)
        self.actor.train(states,q_grads)
        self.actor.update()
        self.critic.update()


env = gym.make('Pendulum-v0')

state_size = env.observation_space.shape[0]
action_size = 1
action_bound = env.action_space.high
agent = DDPG(sess, state_size, action_size, action_bound)


scores, episodes = [], []

for e in range(EPISODES):
    done = False
    score = 0
    state = env.reset()
    state = np.reshape(state, [1,state_size])
    step = 0

    while not done:

        action = agent.get_action(state)
        #print(action)
        next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step([action])
        next_state = np.reshape(next_state,[1,state_size])

        score += reward[0]
        agent.append(state, action, reward, next_state, done)
        state = next_state

        step += 1
        if step % 20 == 0:
          agent.train()

        if done:

            scores.append(score)
            episodes.append(e)
            pylab.plot(episodes, scores, 'b')
            pylab.savefig("./DDPG_Pendulum.png")
            print("episode:", e, " score:", score, " epsilon:", agent.epsilon)

            #if np.mean(scores[-min(10, len(scores)) :]) > -120 :
                #sys.exit()


    if e % 50 == 0:
        agent.save()
```

always i got around -1450 reward per episode

Comment: I took your posted code and at form episode 1610-1632 the average score = -293 with a sd of 225.  From 1710-1732 the mean was -216 and the sd is 251.  It's still negative, there is a lot of back and forth in the scores and it runs slowly on my computer but right now it looks like the score might eventually become positive.

Comment: i run this code around 5000 times on colab after post this code but still i got nothing more than around -1000

Comment: Can you please send me those weights file and png image so that i can find the problem. Thank You

Comment: Thank you for your afford but i think now my model is working well. I think it's about random seed which i haven't fixed. Any suggestion about it will be helpful Thank you

Comment: DDPG can take a lot of time to converge and may work very poorly with the mountain car, which has sparse reward. Try with Pendulum-v0 for a simple benchmark, to check if your algorithm is working, it is much easier to solve.

Comment: Can we try different reward function to deal with that ?